# How to route Popup Login to Login Handler in webapp2 GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

In webapp2, The standard way to handle post method of page is to redirect the url i.e `self.redirect('/login')` to URI route `(r'/login', Login)`.

My problem is, if I will use a popup login (a div element, set display: none), how would I write URI routing to trigger Login Handler?

I hope I was able to made myself clear since I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: Your english is fine no worries, but your case not so clear. Can you provide a little bit more background on what you're trying to achieve ? I mean what is the context ?

Comment: @brian I was also having trouble on how to express my problem :) Anyway, thanks. How would I trigger `Class Login(weapp2Handler)` which is the handler of `(r'/login/, Login)` URI Route, if using popup login, you no longer need to change the URL or do a `redirect()` method? My popup login is just a piece of a div tag inside the current page which is manipulated by jquery. Sorry if this is somewhat misleading.

Comment: here's my simple code to demonstrate how the process works [link](http://pastebin.com/bPjKdQaT)

Comment: Ok I get your handler, now can you walk me through the steps of your app. When does the popup show up ? What is displayed inside your popup ? What do you expect if your user is not logged in ? What do you expect if your user is in fact logged in ? The way your handler is done right now will display the 'home.html' page inside the popup, is it what you want ?

Comment: The Popup Login will show up when the user clicks the Login button on the static header. It requests user account details i.e. username and password. However, when the user fails to login, this `err_msg="Login Failed!"` parameter will appear on the div tag. But when the user has succesfully logged in, the Popup login will just close but still on the same page. Since I'm using jinja2, I just inherited my header div using `{% block header %}`, so the user can access Popup Login anywhere on the page.